# How do I fix "ValueError: time data '\nJuly 4, 2022\n' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'"?

Tags: python, django, datetime

While scrapping a site for data i got that error. Some of the dates are in mm d, yyyy format while others are in mm dd,yyyy. I've read the documentation and tried different solutions on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def jobScan(link):
     
    the_job = {}

    jobUrl = link['href']
    the_job['urlLink'] = jobUrl
   
    jobs = requests.get(jobUrl, headers = headers )
    jobC = jobs.content
    jobSoup = BeautifulSoup(jobC, "lxml")

    table = soup.find_all("a", attrs = {"class": "job-details-link"})

    postDate = jobSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "job-date__posted"})[0]
    postDate = postDate.text
    date_posted = datetime.strptime(postDate, '%B %d, %Y')
    the_job['date_posted'] = date_posted

    closeDate = jobSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "job-date__closing"})[0]
    closeDate = closeDate.text
    closing_date = datetime.strptime(closeDate, '%B %d, %Y')
    the_job['closing_date'] = closing_date
    
    return the_job
```

however i get this error

```
ValueError: time data '\nJuly 4, 2022\n' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'
```

and when i try the other format i get this

```
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%B %-d, %Y'
```

What could I probably be doing wrong?

Comment: The newline characters at beginning and end of the date must be removed. String method "strip" can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
date_posted = datetime.strptime(postDate.replace('\n',''), '%B %d, %Y')
```

Comment: This worked, I still had to do additional formating for some of them but was surely a step in the right direction.  Just as  @Michael Butscher
stated. "datetime.strptime(postDate.strip('\n'), '%B %d, %Y')" works as well